# Join some rows in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

i have this structure of datatable:

```
TYPE   CODE    VALUE    NAME
-----------------------------
D       123     -4      example1
D       123     5       example1
R       123     1       example1
D       444     5       example2
R       777     -2      example3
```

I want to sum rows, where TYPE and CODE are the same.
Result will should be:

```
TYPE   CODE    VALUE    NAME
-----------------------------
D       123     1       example1
R       123     1       example1
D       444     5       example2
R       777     -2      example3
```

Have you any ideas please? Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried to get this working so far?

Comment: I try this:   data = data.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => new {Col1 = r["TYPE"], Col2 = r["CODE"]})
                .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r[VALUE]).(?????)
                    .CopyToDataTable();

Comment: And what result did that give you?

Comment: I havent result, because i dont know, how i could sum the VALUE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = (from p in ur_data_table.AsEnumerable()
            group p by new{ col1 = p["TYPE"],  col2 = 
                                p["CODE"] , col3 = p["NAME"]}
            into groupedTable
            select new
            {
            X = groupedTable.Key,
             //Each Key contains col1,col2 & col3
            VALUE = groupedTable.Sum((s1) =>
                       int.Parse(s1["VALUE"].ToString()))
             }).ToList();
```

Here first `your datatable` will convert as `Ienumerable object` and will group the table with the `three columns` according to which sum need to be done and save as a table name `groupedTable`. Then from grouped table we select the values, where `X` will contain all the columns used for grouping with the help of `Key`. The the last part is to sum the values by parsing it into `int` considering that column only contain `int`. If the datatype is different parse accordingly. Hope this will help.

Comment: And if i have in the datatable columns for example SURNAME, COLOR...how could i give to grouptable?

Comment: `{ col1 = p["TYPE"],  col2 = 
    p["CODE"] , col3 = p["NAME"],col4=p["SURNAME"]......}` just give comma seperated inside the new with a name

Comment: @Jane if those columns are not grouped u may get duplicate rows..because you are using an aggregate function sum in select

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78314/discussion-between-sachu-and-jane).